# Trying to use NSFetchedResultsController to integrate CoreData into my UITableView, but it fails as soon as the app launches

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've been following [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller) tutorial to a T, but when I run my app, it fails on launch every time with the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a
>   legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name
>   'ArticleInfo''

But I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong that would cause that. As a background for what I've done, I have the datamodel file with an entity called ArticleInfo with a bunch of attributes of different types (some transient, if that's of note). Following the advice of [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started) article I subclassed `NSManagedObject` as `ArticleInfo`.

If it's worth noting, I made the `preview`, `wordsInBody` and `progress` transient in the datamodel (and I gave `position` a default value of `0` in the Data Model Inspector). So in the subclass I made custom getters as follows:

```
- (NSString *)preview {
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"preview"];
    NSString *preview = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"preview"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"preview"];

    if (self.body.length < 200) {
        preview = self.body;
    }
    else {
        preview = [self.body substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 200)];
    }

    return preview;
}

- (NSNumber *)progress {
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"progress"];
    NSNumber *progress = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"progress"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"progress"];

    if (self.body.length == 0) {
        progress = @100;
    }
    else {
        progress = @(100 * [self.position intValue] / [self.wordsInBody intValue]);
    }

    return progress;
}

- (NSNumber *)wordsInBody {
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"wordsInBody"];
    NSNumber *wordsInBody = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"wordsInBody"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"wordsInBody"];

    if (!wordsInBody) {
        __block int numberOfWordsInBody = 0;
        NSRange range = {0, self.body.length};
        [self.body enumerateSubstringsInRange:range options:NSStringEnumerationByWords usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
            numberOfWordsInBody++;
        }];

        wordsInBody = @(numberOfWordsInBody);
    }

    return wordsInBody;
}
```

(Again, not sure if that's relevant.)

Now in my main viewcontroller class (the one that has the tableview I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController` for) I declared the property, and overrode its getter:

In .h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
```

In .m:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (!_fetchedResultsController) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ArticleInfo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        request.entity = entity;

        NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];

        request.fetchBatchSize = 20;

        NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
        _fetchedResultsController = fetchedResultsController;
        _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

But again, it keeps giving me that error on app launch. What exactly am I doing wrong that's causing that error?

Comment: Did you check if `context` is `nil` in `[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ArticleInfo" inManagedObjectContext:context]` ? Because that is what the error message states.

Comment: Indeed, but how can the context be `nil`?

Comment: It should be initialized somewhere in your AppDelegate. Perhaps use the debugger to check if and when the context is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ArticleInfo" inManagedObjectContext:context]

Something here is nil. Log context and entity to see which one. Maybe your entity name in your model isn't "ArticleInfo" (typo?) or your app delegate has a problem creating the context.